Using case_when for multiple conditions
Hi am new to R and to StackOverflow.
I am trying to use case_when based on the Scoring Interpretation for asq_vers: version of question completed and asq_t: score obtained. However, it does not seem to be giving the correct output (some of it are correct and some of it are wrong).
Anyone knows how to fix this? Thank you!
Have tried the following code and double checked the scoring and it seems like it should work but it's not giving the correct results.
Sample Data:
asq_test_data <- structure(list(id = c(207L, 203L, 200L, 220L, 204L, 227L, 222L, 
                      212L, 210L, 222L, 225L, 222L, 220L, 213L, 202L, 223L, 229L, 211L, 
                      217L, 205L, 226L, 203L, 220L, 216L, 209L, 220L, 229L, 205L, 214L, 
                      205L, 220L, 224L, 220L, 217L, 225L, 223L, 229L, 204L, 202L, 207L, 
                      230L, 204L, 208L, 209L, 208L, 217L, 214L, 212L, 217L, 225L, 228L, 
                      214L, 201L, 207L, 213L, 218L, 212L, 212L, 210L, 213L), timepoint = c("Pre", 
                                                                                           "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", 
                                                                                           "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", 
                                                                                           "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", 
                                                                                           "Pre", "Pre", "Post", "Post", "Post", "Post", "Post", "Post", 
                                                                                           "Post", "Post", "Post", "Post", "Post", "Post", "Post", "Post", 
                                                                                           "Post", "Post", "Post", "Post", "Post", "Post", "Post", "Post", 
                                                                                           "Post", "Post", "Post", "Post", "Post", "Post", "Post", "Post"
                      ), asq_vers = c("30-month questionnaire (27m0d-32m30d)", "30-month questionnaire (27m0d-32m30d)", 
                                      "12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)", "12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)", 
                                      "18-month questionnaire (15m0d-20m30d)", "36-month questionnaire (33d0m-41m30d)", 
                                      "36-month questionnaire (33d0m-41m30d)", "6-month questionnaire (3m0d - 8m30d)", 
                                      "12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)", "48-month questionnaire (42m0d-53m30d)", 
                                      "12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)", "12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)", 
                                      "6-month questionnaire (3m0d - 8m30d)", "6-month questionnaire (3m0d - 8m30d)", 
                                      "24-month questionnaire (21m0d-26m30d)", "24-month questionnaire (21m0d-26m30d)", 
                                      "24-month questionnaire (21m0d-26m30d)", "36-month questionnaire (33d0m-41m30d)", 
                                      "24-month questionnaire (21m0d-26m30d)", "12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)", 
                                      "36-month questionnaire (33d0m-41m30d)", "6-month questionnaire (3m0d - 8m30d)", 
                                      "12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)", "12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)", 
                                      "18-month questionnaire (15m0d-20m30d)", "6-month questionnaire (3m0d - 8m30d)", 
                                      "6-month questionnaire (3m0d - 8m30d)", "24-month questionnaire (21m0d-26m30d)", 
                                      "30-month questionnaire (27m0d-32m30d)", "6-month questionnaire (3m0d - 8m30d)", 
                                      "36-month questionnaire (33d0m-41m30d)", "36-month questionnaire (33d0m-41m30d)", 
                                      "12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)", "12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)", 
                                      "24-month questionnaire (21m0d-26m30d)", "48-month questionnaire (42m0d-53m30d)", 
                                      "36-month questionnaire (33d0m-41m30d)", "12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)", 
                                      "6-month questionnaire (3m0d - 8m30d)", "12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)", 
                                      "12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)", "48-month questionnaire (42m0d-53m30d)", 
                                      "30-month questionnaire (27m0d-32m30d)", "12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)", 
                                      "12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)", "24-month questionnaire (21m0d-26m30d)", 
                                      "24-month questionnaire (21m0d-26m30d)", "12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)", 
                                      "12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)", "36-month questionnaire (33d0m-41m30d)", 
                                      "24-month questionnaire (21m0d-26m30d)", "36-month questionnaire (33d0m-41m30d)", 
                                      "18-month questionnaire (15m0d-20m30d)", "12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)", 
                                      "6-month questionnaire (3m0d - 8m30d)", "18-month questionnaire (15m0d-20m30d)", 
                                      "30-month questionnaire (27m0d-32m30d)", "6-month questionnaire (3m0d - 8m30d)", 
                                      "12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)", "24-month questionnaire (21m0d-26m30d)"
                      ), asq_t = c("40", "40", "40", "40", "10", "25", "70", "40", 
                                   "55", "80", "10", "10", "25", "25", "10", "115", "115", "70", 
                                   "40", "25", "75", "20", "50", "60", "70", "30", "55", "50", "75", 
                                   "55", "60", "60", "20", "20", "45", "70", "70", "70", "25", "35", 
                                   "40", "25", "30", "15", "15", "85", "85", "0", "35", "60", "65", 
                                   "50", "65", "45", "30", "80", "50", "40", "70", "35")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                         -60L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


case_when


asq_test_data <- asq_test_data %>% 
  mutate(asq_interpretation = case_when(
    asq_vers == "6-month questionnaire (3m0d - 8m30d)" & asq_t <= 30 ~ "No or low risk",
    asq_vers == "6-month questionnaire (3m0d - 8m30d)" & asq_t <= 45 ~ "Monitor",
    asq_vers == "6-month questionnaire (3m0d - 8m30d)" & asq_t <= 55 ~ "Further assessment needed",
    asq_vers == "6-month questionnaire (3m0d - 8m30d)" & asq_t > 55 ~ "Further assessment needed (90%tile)",
    
    asq_vers == "12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)" & asq_t <= 40 ~ "No or low risk",
    asq_vers == "12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)" & asq_t <= 50 ~ "Monitor",
    asq_vers == "12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)" & asq_t<= 75 ~ "Further assessment needed",
    asq_vers == "12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)" & asq_t > 75 ~ "Further assessment needed (90%tile)",
    
    asq_vers == "18-month questionnaire (15m0d-20m30d)" & asq_t <= 50 ~ "No or low risk",
    asq_vers == "18-month questionnaire (15m0d-20m30d)" & asq_t > 50 & asq_t <= 65 ~ "Monitor",
    asq_vers == "18-month questionnaire (15m0d-20m30d)" & asq_t > 65 & asq_t <= 105 ~ "Further assessment needed",
    asq_vers == "18-month questionnaire (15m0d-20m30d)" & asq_t > 105 ~ "Further assessment needed (90%tile)",
    
    asq_vers == "24-month questionnaire (21m0d-26m30d)" & asq_t >= 0 & asq_t <= 50 ~ "No or low risk",
    asq_vers == "24-month questionnaire (21m0d-26m30d)" & asq_t > 50 & asq_t <= 65 ~ "Monitor",
    asq_vers == "24-month questionnaire (21m0d-26m30d)" & asq_t > 65 & asq_t <= 110 ~ "Further assessment needed",
    asq_vers == "24-month questionnaire (21m0d-26m30d)" & asq_t > 110 ~ "Further assessment needed (90%tile)",
    
    asq_vers == "30-month questionnaire (27m0d-32m30d)" & asq_t >= 0 & asq_t <= 65 ~ "No or low risk",
    asq_vers == "30-month questionnaire (27m0d-32m30d)" & asq_t > 65 & asq_t <= 85 ~ "Monitor",
    asq_vers == "30-month questionnaire (27m0d-32m30d)" & asq_t > 85 & asq_t <= 135 ~ "Further assessment needed",
    asq_vers == "30-month questionnaire (27m0d-32m30d)" & asq_t > 135 ~ "Further assessment needed (90%tile)",
    
    asq_vers == "36-month questionnaire (33m0d-41m30d)" & asq_t <= 75 ~ "No or low risk",
    asq_vers == "36-month questionnaire (33m0d-41m30d)" & asq_t <= 105 ~ "Monitor",
    asq_vers == "36-month questionnaire (33m0d-41m30d)" & asq_t <= 155 ~ "Further assessment needed",
    asq_vers == "36-month questionnaire (33m0d-41m30d)" & asq_t > 155 ~ "Further assessment needed (90%tile)",
    
    asq_vers == "48-month questionnaire (42m0d-53m30d)" & asq_t <= 70 ~ "No or low risk",
    asq_vers == "48-month questionnaire (42m0d-53m30d)" & asq_t > 70 & asq_t <= 85 ~ "Monitor",
    asq_vers == "48-month questionnaire (42m0d-53m30d)" & asq_t > 85 & asq_t <= 150 ~ "Further assessment needed",
    asq_vers == "48-month questionnaire (42m0d-53m30d)" & asq_t > 150 ~ "Further assessment needed (90%tile)",
    TRUE ~ "No category"
  ))

print.data.frame(asq_test_data)

Some of the results are correct but some are totally off (e.g. row 16 & 17 - should be "Further assessment needed (90%tile)" , 46 & 47 - ""Further assessment needed"):
    id timepoint                              asq_vers asq_t                  asq_interpretation
1  207       Pre 30-month questionnaire (27m0d-32m30d)    40                      No or low risk
2  203       Pre 30-month questionnaire (27m0d-32m30d)    40                      No or low risk
3  200       Pre  12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)    40                      No or low risk
4  220       Pre  12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)    40                      No or low risk
5  204       Pre 18-month questionnaire (15m0d-20m30d)    10                      No or low risk
6  227       Pre 36-month questionnaire (33d0m-41m30d)    25                         No category
7  222       Pre 36-month questionnaire (33d0m-41m30d)    70                         No category
8  212       Pre  6-month questionnaire (3m0d - 8m30d)    40                             Monitor
9  210       Pre  12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)    55           Further assessment needed
10 222       Pre 48-month questionnaire (42m0d-53m30d)    80                             Monitor
11 225       Pre  12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)    10                      No or low risk
12 222       Pre  12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)    10                      No or low risk
13 220       Pre  6-month questionnaire (3m0d - 8m30d)    25                      No or low risk
14 213       Pre  6-month questionnaire (3m0d - 8m30d)    25                      No or low risk
15 202       Pre 24-month questionnaire (21m0d-26m30d)    10                      No or low risk
16 223       Pre 24-month questionnaire (21m0d-26m30d)   115                      No or low risk
17 229       Pre 24-month questionnaire (21m0d-26m30d)   115                      No or low risk
18 211       Pre 36-month questionnaire (33d0m-41m30d)    70                         No category
19 217       Pre 24-month questionnaire (21m0d-26m30d)    40                      No or low risk
20 205       Pre  12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)    25                      No or low risk
21 226       Pre 36-month questionnaire (33d0m-41m30d)    75                         No category
22 203       Pre  6-month questionnaire (3m0d - 8m30d)    20                      No or low risk
23 220       Pre  12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)    50                             Monitor
24 216       Pre  12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)    60           Further assessment needed
25 209       Pre 18-month questionnaire (15m0d-20m30d)    70 Further assessment needed (90%tile)
26 220       Pre  6-month questionnaire (3m0d - 8m30d)    30                      No or low risk
27 229       Pre  6-month questionnaire (3m0d - 8m30d)    55           Further assessment needed
28 205       Pre 24-month questionnaire (21m0d-26m30d)    50                      No or low risk
29 214       Pre 30-month questionnaire (27m0d-32m30d)    75                             Monitor
30 205       Pre  6-month questionnaire (3m0d - 8m30d)    55           Further assessment needed
31 220      Post 36-month questionnaire (33d0m-41m30d)    60                         No category
32 224      Post 36-month questionnaire (33d0m-41m30d)    60                         No category
33 220      Post  12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)    20                      No or low risk
34 217      Post  12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)    20                      No or low risk
35 225      Post 24-month questionnaire (21m0d-26m30d)    45                      No or low risk
36 223      Post 48-month questionnaire (42m0d-53m30d)    70                      No or low risk
37 229      Post 36-month questionnaire (33d0m-41m30d)    70                         No category
38 204      Post  12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)    70           Further assessment needed
39 202      Post  6-month questionnaire (3m0d - 8m30d)    25                      No or low risk
40 207      Post  12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)    35                      No or low risk
41 230      Post  12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)    40                      No or low risk
42 204      Post 48-month questionnaire (42m0d-53m30d)    25                      No or low risk
43 208      Post 30-month questionnaire (27m0d-32m30d)    30                      No or low risk
44 209      Post  12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)    15                      No or low risk
45 208      Post  12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)    15                      No or low risk
46 217      Post 24-month questionnaire (21m0d-26m30d)    85 Further assessment needed (90%tile)
47 214      Post 24-month questionnaire (21m0d-26m30d)    85 Further assessment needed (90%tile)
48 212      Post  12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)     0                      No or low risk
49 217      Post  12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)    35                      No or low risk
50 225      Post 36-month questionnaire (33d0m-41m30d)    60                         No category
51 228      Post 24-month questionnaire (21m0d-26m30d)    65                             Monitor
52 214      Post 36-month questionnaire (33d0m-41m30d)    50                         No category
53 201      Post 18-month questionnaire (15m0d-20m30d)    65                             Monitor
54 207      Post  12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)    45                             Monitor
55 213      Post  6-month questionnaire (3m0d - 8m30d)    30                      No or low risk
56 218      Post 18-month questionnaire (15m0d-20m30d)    80 Further assessment needed (90%tile)
57 212      Post 30-month questionnaire (27m0d-32m30d)    50                      No or low risk
58 212      Post  6-month questionnaire (3m0d - 8m30d)    40                             Monitor
59 210      Post  12-month questionnaire (9m0d-14m30d)    70           Further assessment needed
60 213      Post 24-month questionnaire (21m0d-26m30d)    35                      No or low risk


Your asq_t variable is a character variable. So, applying a numeric condition on it, will lead to unexpected results. Turn this variable into a numeric one by as.numeric(asq_t) before running the case_when.

As deschen suggests in a comment, running
asq_test_data$asq_t <- as.numeric(asq_test_data$asq_t)

before mutate, produces the correct result.
As explained here, comparing a string to a numeric will compare them both in lexicographic order, e.g.
> "115" <= 65
[1] TRUE

because 1 comes before 6 in the alphabet.
Casting the string as numeric corrects the error:
> as.numeric("115") <= 65
[1] FALSE

